# Basement Floor Cracks

Tags: concrete, basement, floor

I have very thin cracks in my basement floor and I'm attempting to patch them before trying my hand at acid staining the floor.

I've read some differing opinions on the use of hydraulic cement or urethane.

I plan to chisel out the cracks a bit beforehand, after that what product is best?

Thanks!

Comment: Cracks happen, many times with no concern. I would be more concerned how the concrete stain would take differently on the repair compared to the rest of the floor

Comment: Good point, so I should go for something that will stain well.  Thanks!

Comment: Nothing will stain the same as the concrete floor, what I am trying to say is unless a picture reveals the cracks are structural failure. Minor cracking that normally occurs in the curing of concrete or the seasonal movement, is of no concern. I would leave the crack alone, stain the floor, and then if that bothers you, then treat the cracks with something that is color compatible with the new color or even a clear caulk which will pull the color of the floor and its' variations.

Comment: Why do you want to patch them before staining?  Do they cause a "bump"?